# Can I create an object in windows form1.cs so I then can use the object and the objects contents in multiple click events (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class, object

Can I create an object in `windows form1.cs` so that I then can use it and the contents of the object in multiple click events in the windows form1.cs file?

This is the code that demonstrates my intention:

```
namespace example
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {

        // here i want to call a class an make an objekt thats contains list of "books" from other 
        // classes 
        // (classname variable = new classname)


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // here I want to use the object made from the code above.
           // variable.function() 
        }

        private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // here I want to use the object made from the code above.
           // variable.function()
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

       // is there anyway to do this or is it another place that makes the object reachable from the 
       // places I want to call it?

    }
}
```

Comment: You can introduce a private member in the form class, check for [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Private member can be accessed from any method within same class.  Note, that form is just another c# class.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new file and create a new class in it. The thing you look for is a field. A field is a variable that belongs to the instance of the class.

Here is an example:  *(added some extra to your code)*

```
namespace exemple   // <--- I know this is spelled wrong, but I'm using the original code, I'm not a spelling checker ;-)
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // the declaration of the field (you can instantiate it here as well) 
        private BookCase _bookCase;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();     

            // create an instance of the bookcase and store in into a field.       
            _bookCase = new BookCase();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // add some books.
            _bookCase.Add(new Book { Title = "Something", Author = "John" };
            _bookCase.Add(new Book { Title = "Anything", Author = "Doe" };
            // variable.function()**

        }

        private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call a method of the bookcase
            _bookCase.ShowBooks();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

       /**/ is there anyway to do this or is it another place thats make the objekt reachable from the 
       // places i whant to call it?**

    }
}
```

---

```
namespace exemple
{
    // just a book class
    public class Book
    {
        // with some properties
        public string Title {get;set;}
        public string Author {get;set;}
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace exemple
{
    // a bookcase which contains a list of books store in a field
    public class BookCase
    {
        private List<Book> _books = new List<Book>();

        public void Add(Book book)
        {
            // add a book
            _books.Add(book);
        }

        public void ShowBooks()
        {
            // show all books
            foreach(var book in _books)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Title: {book.Title}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll read through your example a few times and see if I understand what I've done wrong. Then I can make changes to my program and we will see if it works.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, you're just missing something ;-)

Comment: halfway there. Now I'm going to sleep and I can continue tomorrow. Thanks for now.

Comment: Solved it. Took some structural ideas from what you wrote. However, it did a little different but it helped me a lot in understanding how to do to succeed in getting objects from the class to work.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want following :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.TextChanged +=  new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
            textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
            textBox3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think that this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: dosen't fels like The solution for my problem.
 se if i can explain  my problem more.

I have a windows form program. in this program i hav a clas that reads txt files. return it like an list of arrays. that list another class makes objekts of thats stored in another list of "books" roman, novells etc etc. The list of books are in a class that i whant to make a new objet of in my winodows form. and i whant to call that objekt in difrent click events. 

little bit messy

Comment: Create a method that is not in a click event.  More than one click event can call same method.  This way common code that is shared between click events do not have to be duplicated.